# Proper Primary Key for child table?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key, query-performance

What should the Primary key be in the Employee Table?

```
Table Stores
(PK) StoreID
{other store columns}

Table Employee
StoreID
EmployeeID
{other employee columns...}
```

[Edit]
Our setup is such that an employee will always belong to one store only.  Every employee should have a unique ID (ie, even if employees belong to different stores, they should never have the same ID).

I think the PK should be EmployeeID only, since it should ALWAYS be unique.  My coworker thinks the PK should be compounded with StoreID+EmployeeID, but then it would be (theoretically) possible to have duplicate employee IDs.  I don't entirely follow his reasoning, but one thing he cited is performance.  I am not too worried about query performance since for our database the Employee table has never exceeded 5000 records.  We do have other, larger child tables that reference StoreID, is this a valid reason to create such a key?

[Edit]
Would the compound PK be okay if you also created an internal key that enforces uniqueness on only EmployeeID?  Maybe there are multiple ways to do this, but I want to pick the most accepted practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your EmployeeID is unique across all stores, then it should be the primary key of that table. Like you said, otherwise you would have duplicate EmployeeIDs. The only reason I can see to have StoreID + EmployeeID is that if each store had its own employee numbers. If a person worked in two differnet stores, he would then need two EmployeeIDs, one for each store. From your question though, I don't think that is the case.

The StoreID should, however, be setup with a Foreign Key relationship, assuming that the employee will always be assigned a StoreID.

Also, if your co-worker is mainly concerned with performance, you can add an EmployeeID, StoreID index to your table, that should clear up any slow queries (if you encounter any). Since you said the table was small, I would wait until a performance issue appeared before adding indexes. I think the primary key is always a logical organization decision, I wouldn't consider performance as part of that decision.

Comment: You interepreted correctly, empID is unique across entire database.  I updated the Q to clarify.  I agree entirely with your assessment, that PK needs to reflect the unique column(s) of the table.  I don't know whether I should give you the answer now or wait a bit, as I was hoping for more comments.  Since this is a verbal spat, the more supporting opinions I can point to the better.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the PK should be EmployeeID only, since it should ALWAYS be
>   unique. My coworker thinks the PK should be compounded with
>   StoreID+EmployeeID, but then it would be (theoretically) possible to
>   have duplicate employee IDs.

You're talking about two slightly different things.

If you want *only* to identify employees, then the primary key should probably be employee_id, and the id number of the store shouldn't be in that table at all. *But* if, in addition, you want to know which store an employee usually works at, you can either include the store_id in the employees table (and make it `NOT NULL`), or you can create a separate table.

In the 25+ years I've been doing this stuff, I've often had people tell me that an employee can work at *only* one store. That's almost always untrue, often even at the moment the managers are swearing it *is* true. One time, we were "discussing" this in a room with half a dozen employees who all worked at more than one store. One of them worked at five different stores every week. And *all* the managers knew this. When we pointed out all the people who worked at more than one store, the managers still insisted that everyone worked at only one store. (shrug)

I favor using a separate table to store employees current, paid work locations. The main reason is that management *always* want more information about that relationship besides *just* that bare fact.  Always. Attendance, timekeeping, always something else.

In *that* table, you'll need a composite primary key of at least {store_id, employee_id}. You might need more columns (and sometimes more tables) than that, depending on what other information you want to store about that location relationship.  You'll also need some kind of administrative procedure (which you might or might not be able to automate) to make sure every employee has at least one current, paid work location. (If you dbms ever supports assertions, you can get rid of the administrative procedure.)

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear on the rules. In our case, the employee will ALWAYS belong to just one store, and the EmpID is supposed to be unique across the entire database. My database is not actually about Employees and Stores, I'm just substituting them as intuitive examples. Though I agree that your solution would prolly work for real employees :)